# Regex to match S3 file and a directory

Tags: java, regex

I have the following pattern that used to match a `S3` URL

```
Pattern.compile("^s3://([^/]+)/(.*?([^/]+))$");
```

This matches

```
s3://bucket/path/key
```

But does not match a directory

```
s3://bucket/path/directory/
```

Is there an easy way to change the `pattern` to match a directory?

Answer (score 6):

There's only the final slash missing in the regex. You might try this:

```
^s3://([^/]+)/(.*?([^/]+)/?)$
                         ^^
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/gM5eD8).

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine in JS but will work for all languages supporting RegEx too I guess.Somebody might want to use this for a sample path ,like this

*s3://bucket_name/folder1/folder2/file1.json*

```
^s3:\/\/([^/]+)\/([\w\W]+)\.(.*)
```